C# WPF Error no se puede usar este archivo se esta usando en otro caso
tengo un error, al sobreescribir en poco tiempo un archivo ya escrito me salta el error que el archivo que quiero utilizar se esta usando en otra parte
if (facturah.sellorecepcion.Trim() == "") { MessageBox.Show("Se encontro que el documento no esta sellado."); return; }
        if (facturah.impreso == 0)
        {

            try
            {
                File.WriteAllBytes(elpdte.rdte + @"\DTE_DOC.pdf", viewerInstance.LocalReport.Render("PDF"));
               //File.WriteAllBytes(rutaPDF, viewerInstance.LocalReport.Render("PDF"));
                
                //Generar el JSON y enviar el correo electrónico
                generarjson(Mycodfactura);
                sendmail(Mycodfactura);
               
            }
            catch 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("se ah generado un error, por favor intentalo mas tarde");
                return;
            }
            dl_generica _dll = new dl_generica();
            String SQL = "UPDATE " + variables_publicas.dbfacturacion + ".factura_h set impreso = 1 where cod_factura='" + facturah.cod_factura + "'";
            _dll.transacSQL(SQL);
        }

mencionar que esta parte genera un JSon y un PDf que son enviados por correo electronico mediante una API que puedo hacer para cerrar el uso antes de sobre escribir?

Usar File.WriteAllBytesAsync

podrias darme un ejemplo de uso? tengo entendido que file no tiene una caracteristica writeallbyteAsync

Al menos está en .net 8.0, cual versión estas usando tu?

trabajo en un .net 4, no creo que pueda adaptar caracteristicas asi
